# PHP how to keep the already uploaded file in the edit form

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I have uploaded a file in my database below row named 'file_name'. Now when I open my edit form in view mode, the file name does not show (is empty) and when I save the form, the file_name goes blank from the database. I want to save the file in edit form so each time I save the form, the already uploaded file should show in database. I know that value cannot be used for files for security reasons and I also know how to just echo the name of file, but I need to keep the already uploaded file in edit form.

This is my code in edit form in view mode:

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="example-text"><?php echo get_phrase('Browse File');?></label>
     <input type="file" name="file_name" id = "file_name" class="form-control-file"/><span name="old" id = "old"><?php echo $row['file_name'];?></span>
</div>
```

This is my code in model:

```html
$page_data['file_name'] = $_FILES["file_name"]["name"];
$oldfile = $_POST['old'];
$file = $_FILES["file_name"]["name"];
  if($file != "") {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/parents_image/" . $_FILES["file_name"]["name"]); 
   } else {
     $file = $oldfile;
     $page_data['file_name'] = $this->input->post('file_name');
   }
```

Any advice would be very helpful.
Many thanks. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE9s2.png)

Comment: have your problem is solved or not???

Comment: Nope, not yet. I am still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_name']) &&  !empty($_FILES['file_name']){
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I put the following code but is still not working:                      
        $oldfile = $_POST['old'];
        $file = $_FILES["file_name"]["name"];

        if(isset($_FILES['file_name']) && !empty($_FILES['file_name'])){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/parents_image/" . $_FILES["file_name"]["name"]); 
        } else {
            $file = $oldfile;
            $page_data['file_name'] = $this->input->post('file_name');
        }